# how to get the angular filter returned value in controller scope

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to get the angular filter return value in controller scope. I need to pass the returned value of one filter to another filter. I have a filter defined as follows

```
     .filter('Filter', Filter)
function Filter($filter) {

    return FilterFn;

    function FilterFn(data, weight, waist) {
        var factor1 = weight * 1.082 + 94.42;
        var factor2 = waist * 4.15;
        var leanBodyMass = factor1 - factor2;
        var bodyFatWeight = weight - leanBodyMass;
        var bodyFatResults = bodyFatWeight * 100 / weight;
        // return Params
        if (bodyFatResults === "-Infinity") {
            // $filter('Filter2')(0);
            return 0;
        } else if (parseFloat(bodyFatResults) < 0) {
            //  $filter('Filter2')(2);
            return 2;
        } else {
            //  $filter('Filter2')(bodyFatResults.toFixed(1));
            return bodyFatResults.toFixed(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the returned value of this filter in controller scope.

Comment: Generally filters are used to show value on view in slightly formatted way, thats why filters doesn't care about scope. May I know why you want that formatted value inside a scope?

Comment: Based on the formatted value I will set status.

Comment: then use filter manually like shown in below two answers..

Comment: If I use filter inside controller, will it be called whenever the parameter value changes?

Comment: absolutely no.. you have to do that manually each time.

Comment: thanks for spending time for me, i will try using filter inside controller.

Answer (score 2):

Inject $filter inside your controller and use it like that:

```
.controller('Controller', function($filter) {
    var filtered = $filter('Filter2')(data, weight, waist);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can inject the $filter service on your controller and use your custom filters with it:

```
.controller(["filter", function($filter) {

var somevariable = $filter("Filter2")(data, weight, waist);

});
```

See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your filter to your controller, for example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = $filter('yourFilter')();
}])

.filter('yourFilter', function() {
    return 'hello';
});
```